# vuex: how to save data from multiple components?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

If I follow the [vuex state docu](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html) I get a simple counter. Now I can use this counter as a component like this: https://jsfiddle.net/zr86xtqg/. Its easy to note that all counters use the same data (like a component without `data: function(){...}`).

What do I need to do to get a real component with unique data? Should I add an array to the store and push each counter into it?

Sorry for this simple question but I am totally new to this state managment / data handling.

Maybe it's nice to know why I need it: There is a place in my app with a variable mix of components and another place where I have to display some of the component data. I googled a bit and found many recommendation to use vuex.

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    count: 0
  },
  mutations: {
   increment: state => state.count++,
    decrement: state => state.count--
  }
})

Vue.component('test-counter', {
  computed: {
    count () {
     return store.state.count
    }
  },
  template: '<div><p>{{ count }}</p><button @click="increment">+</button><button @click="decrement">-</button><p></div>',
  methods: {
    increment () {
      store.commit('increment')
    },
    decrement () {
     store.commit('decrement')
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuex/3.1.2/vuex.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <test-counter></test-counter>
  <test-counter></test-counter>
</div>
```

Comment: Data unique to each component is stored in the data function.

```data() {
      return {
        text: 'Copy available in this component',
        value: 2  
     }
}```

Comment: do you actually need vuex or are you asking about how to create custom components?

Comment: Yes I know but if I want to use `text` or `value ` in another component I need a state manager / vuex or not? Else it will be nice if you can edit my example :-)

Comment: @Chris, yes you are correct, to have data available in other components you need state management.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

**HTML**

```
<div id="components-demo">
  <button-counter></button-counter>
  <button-counter></button-counter>
  <button-counter></button-counter>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
// Define a new component called button-counter
Vue.component('button-counter', {
  data: function () {
    return {
      count: 0
    }
  },
  template: '<button v-on:click="count++">You clicked me {{ count }} times.</button>'
})

new Vue({ el: '#components-demo' })
```

**DEMO**

https://jsfiddle.net/emanuell_minciu/L4xot38s/

**SOURCE:**

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html

**DEMO UPDATE (Vuex)**

https://jsfiddle.net/emanuell_minciu/Ljno612k/3/

**DEMO UPDATE (based on new requirements)**

https://jsfiddle.net/emanuell_minciu/cr5w87g4/53/

Comment: I know that data must be a function: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function 

But I am looking for a solution in combination with vuex.

Comment: @Chris, I've edited my post with a demo update, see if that helps. Once the store has been updated you can get the state from it in other components by using `store.state`

Comment: Thanks, on the first view it looks good. I will test your code at the weekend!

Comment: Good luck @Chris, let me know if you need any further explanation

Comment: I think my initial wording was a bit unclear. I updated your jsfiddle and I hope it is now clear for what I am looking. Many thanks for your help and time!  https://jsfiddle.net/t905oh1u/

Comment: see atop :) forgot name calling

Comment: @Chris I don't know the full requirements of your problem and working with dummy data makes it difficult to find the best way to approach a good solution. I have added another **jsfiddle** above which covers most of the things you are after (except for the add / remove buttons - I don't know where you want to do these). Hope this helps you get started and finish the task.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you can make multiple store for various modules. Below I'll show you an example that how I make the store for many modules.

**IMPORTANT** I recommend you to use namespace=true, It allow you differenciate from each other

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)


const storeTercero = {
    namespaced:true,
    state: {
        razonSocial: null
    },
    mutations:{
        setRazon(pState, pRazon){
            pState.razonSocial = pRazon
        }
    }
}

const storeFactura = {
    namespaced:true,
    state:{
        numero: null
    },
    mutations:{
        setNumero(pState, pNumero){
            pState.numero = pNumero
        }           
    }
}

const storeProducto = {
    namespaced: true,
    state:{
        arr_pestanas: []
    },
    mutations:{
        setPestanas(pState,pArrPestanas){
            pState.arr_pestanas = pArrPestanas
        },
        setFolia1(pState,pObjFolia1){
            pState.arr_pestanas.folia1 = pObjFolia1
        },
        setCombinaciones(pState,pObjCombinaciones){
            pState.arr_pestanas.push(pObjCombinaciones)
        },
        limpiarPestanas(pState){
            pState.arr_pestanas = []
        },
        actualizarFolia(pState,payload){
            switch (payload.fila) {
                case 1:
                    pState.arr_pestanas[payload.indice].folia1= {
                        valor:payload.objeto.value,
                        texto:payload.objeto.display
                    }
                  break;
                case 2:
                    pState.arr_pestanas[payload.indice].folia2= {
                        valor:payload.objeto.value,
                        texto:payload.objeto.display
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    pState.arr_pestanas[payload.indice].folia3= {
                        valor:payload.objeto.value,
                        texto:payload.objeto.display
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    pState.arr_pestanas[payload.indice].folia1= null
                    pState.arr_pestanas[payload.indice].folia2= null
                    pState.arr_pestanas[payload.indice].folia3= null
                    break;
            }
        },
        eliminarIndice(pState,payload){
            pState.arr_pestanas.splice(payload.indice,1)
        }
    },
    actions:{
        actualizarFolia({commit},payload){
            commit('actualizarFolia',payload)
        },
        cambiarFoliaTodos({state,commit},payload){
            state.arr_pestanas.forEach((valor,indice,array) => {
                commit('actualizarFolia',{
                    indice,
                    fila:payload.fila,
                    objeto:payload.objeto
                })
            });
        },
        eliminarCombinacion({commit},payload){
            if (payload.indice > -1) {
                commit('eliminarIndice',{
                    indice:payload.indice
                })
            }
        }
    },
    getters:{
        pestanasCount: state => {
            return state.arr_pestanas.length
        }
    }
}

const storeCartera = {
    namespaced: true,
    state:{
        arrCarteraPagos: []
    },
    mutations:{
        actualizarVlrPago(pState,payload){
            pState.arrCarteraPagos[payload.fila] = payload.valorPago;
        },
        setVlrCarteraPagos(pState,payload){

            pState.arrCarteraPagos.filter(function(item){
                if(item.id === payload.id){
                    item.valorPagado = payload.vlr;
                }
            })

        },
        setArrCarteraPagos(pState,payload){
            pState.arrCarteraPagos = payload
        }
    }
}

const store = new Vuex.Store({
    strict: true,
    modules:{
        terceros: storeTercero,
        facturas: storeFactura,
        productos: storeProducto,
        cartera: storeCartera
    }
})


export default store
```

Comment: Thanks for the big code but I think I am looking for another solution. I am a total beginner with vue / vuex. My app has only 1 store but I use componentFooBar more than 1 time and I want to save the data in my store. Like this 3 buttons example but with vuex: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Reusing-Components